# How to deploy .net mvc4 web application in cpanel subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cpanel

I want to deploy my simple mvc web application in soewebsite.com , copied all required files to root directory from published application such as bin,content,scripts,web.config.
But site opening file browser with copied files. Need help in this.
Thanks,

Sur

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't do it, because Cpanel works for Linux and ASP.NET apps don't. You need is IIS to run aspx